# Site cannot be reached when graph using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to use plotly to plot a simple graph

My code is shown as follow

```
import plotly.express as px

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
fig = px.line(x=x, y=y,labels={'x':x_name,'y':y_name})
fig.show()
```

when I run this code, sometimes the browser is showing `This site can’t be reached`

I've searched on this question [1](https://community.plotly.com/t/this-site-cant-be-reached-error-when-clicking-zoom-in-r/29697) [2](https://community.plotly.com/t/can-t-reach-my-first-dash/20994) [3](https://community.plotly.com/t/first-figure-never-loads-show-getting-this-site-can-t-be-reached-browser-error/35363) , but did not got any answer.

How should I solve this problem when the browser shows `This site can’t be reached` ?

Comment: When you say “in the browser”, do you mean you run your code in Jupyter? Something else?

Comment: @Roy2012 Hi, I ran the code in visual studio code, and the output is a graph shown in the broswer, however, the broswer displays ```site cannot be reached```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably noticed, the site you're trying to reach is localhost (127.0.0.1). Fig.show() creates a server, the browser goes to this server to fetch the image, and the server then shuts down.

If there's a timing (or some other) issue, you'll get the 'site cannot be reached' message.

The issue seems to be in this part of the plotly code:

```
class OneShotRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

        bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
        for i in range(0, len(html), bufferSize):
            self.wfile.write(html[i : i + bufferSize])

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        # Silence stderr logging
        pass

server = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 0), OneShotRequestHandler)
webbrowser.get(using).open(
    "http://127.0.0.1:%s" % server.server_port, new=new, autoraise=autoraise
)

server.handle_request()
```

(see [code on GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/d43331a897ab5450b33654c103ec73d9003290cd/packages/python/plotly/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py))

My main advice would be to start using Plotly within Jupyter. It works great, and you won't run into this issue.

Answer (score 11):

instead of the fig.show() try using plotly.offline.plot(fig) to plot in offline mode

more details can be found here: https://pythonbasics.org/plotly/

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Fantastic! After much trouble in VS Code using `fig.show()` over the last few months displaying on Google Chrome, this seems to have finally resolved it so that the figures are plotted reproducibly (without sporadic "refused to connect" messages or the code hanging and needing to be restarted).